# How to call ESRISignAddIn Silently (no UI)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, add-in

I am creating a build workflow and I ran into some problems.

When I call [ESRISignAddIn.exe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p0000001w000000) from the command prompt it is throwing up a dialog saying "Add-In successfully signed". I was expecting it to report that back within the cmd dialog and not open up a new messagebox.

Have anyone else seen this or have worked out how to sign an add-in "silently"?

The `/s` switch does not work.

This issue occurs with the 10.2 version of the exe (latest at time) and earlier versions.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRISignAddIn.exe" "C:\temp\my.esriAddIn" /c:"C:\temp\newCert.pfx" /p:myPass
```

Comment: I found exactly the same issue

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Did you try the fairly standard `/s` switch?

Comment: Well I did, and it doesn't work. :P Not sure what the intended workflow is. I have never needed to sign an add-in, I guess.

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: actually just tried /s and it worked for me (10.1 install), just noticed in you answer below \s didn't work but maybe your slash is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a Question best posed to Esri's software developers via your local **[Esri support](http://support.esri.com/en/)**.

If you would expect from its documentation that it should work silently via a `/s` switch then it would seem that there is either a bug, or that a documentation fix/enhancement may be in order.